# Extracting a field with a name including "-" from JSON response in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have been trying to extract this field ""csg-auth-token"" from the JSOn response below in POSTMAN, it seems an easy thing to do which I have done before with other fields, but  this time it's causing problems and not saved properly.
[image]

What I am doing is adding this  javascript in Test and tryng to save that value in a environment variable

```html
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("claims-token", jsonData.csg-auth-token);
```

However Postman returns an error in the console like "ReferenceError: auth is not defined"
It seems Postman is not able to recognize a value in Json with "auth" or the problem is the hyphens "-"??
csg-auth-token
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access this property using `jsonData['csg-auth-token']` instead since it can't be used as a valid identifier in javascript (because of the dashes).

Comment: Great that it worked out! If an answer solves your problem you can mark it as the "accepted" answer by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.